# Session redirect loop on login page work-around advice

Tags: php

I am looking to placing all code above  in header.php which I include.

The first few lines of header has :

```
<?php session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"])){
header("Location: login.php");
exit;}
?>
```

The unfortunate consequence of this is that when the user gets redirected to login.php they hit a redirect loop.

Would the best way forward to be creating an If statement along the lines of pseudo:

```
if (page="login.php")
{
  //do not redirect to login.php
}
```

Before the `session_start();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the code

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"])){
header("Location: login.php");
exit;}
```

In a function such as:

```
function ensureLoggedIn()
{
  if (!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]))
  {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
  }
}
```

Then you call this function from all the pages where authentication is required.

Such as calling this function on secretpage.php will redirect to login.php if the user is not logged in.

Login.php should not have this function.

Comment: Can someone please tell me what is wrong with the code before downvoting it?

Comment: You can start the session with session_start() but don't run the code in the function on logged in file.

Comment: Include the function is_logged_in your header file. Then only call that function from the main file when you need authentication.

Comment: And initiate the session_start() call regardless of calls to that funciton

Comment: You have the right idea, maybe you could correct it, so it is syntactically correct? Also the name of the function is a bit misleading, something like `ensureLoggedIn()` would say more about what the function does (it does not return a value indicating whether the user is logged in). With those corrections you have my vote.

Comment: @martinstoeckli changed. Thanks. My mind is going in circles today.

Comment: "This account is temporarily suspended for voting irregularities. The suspension period ends in 4 days" lol

Comment: @l2aelba that was bound to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Before includeing header in login.php, do something like this:

```
$logging_in = true;
```

Then, modify header

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"])){
```

to

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && !isset($logging_in))
```

Answer (score -2):

In your login page you can check if the user is already logged in and redirect them to proper page.

```
<?php
 if( userIsLoggedIn ){
  //redirect to main page page or logout them forcefully
 }
?>

//your login form can go here
```